# Get all items of listbox by converting it in string values

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have listbox and its items are the selected dates from Calendar control in ASP.net. Now I need to filter them in foreach loop according to whether every single date is present database table or not. And the code for same I used is like as:

```
foreach (string item in ListBoxSelectedDates.Items)
{
    string q = "select count(*) from event_calendar where _date='" + Convert.ToDateTime(item).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, conn);
    conn.Open();
    if ((long)(cmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0) == 0)
    {

        strBody += i + ". " + Convert.ToDateTime(item).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(item).DayOfWeek + "  : Leave <br>";
        i++;
    }
    else
    {

        strBody += i + ". " + Convert.ToDateTime(item).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(item).DayOfWeek + "  : Holiday <br>";
        i++;
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

And getting error at first line of above code is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to
>   type 'System.String'.

I am not getting proper solution after continuously trying...

Comment: would it not work if you replaced foreach (string item in ListBoxSelectedDates.Items) with foreach (var item in ListBoxSelectedDates.Items) ?

Comment: no it would't, because ListItem couldn't be converted implicitly to string. So the extra step through .Value or .ToString() is necessary. This is why the OP gets the Error, if he changes it, as you suggested, it would move the thrown error 1 line down to the SQL String.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ListItem.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method to convert the ListItem to a String.

```
foreach (var _iterator in ListBoxSelectedDates.Items)
{
    string item = _iterator.ToString();

    //The rest of your logic here

    conn.Close();
}
```

---

If you want to access explicitly the value, you can have a look to the [`ListItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation, there you can see that there is a public property called `Value` so you can use instead:

```
string item = _iterator.Value;
```

so you get:

```
foreach (ListItem _iterator in ListBoxSelectedDates.Items)
{
    string item = _iterator.Value;

    //The rest of your logic here

    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (var _iterator in ListBoxSelectedDates.Items)                 // here "lstDate" is name of your list where you store all date.
            {
                string item = _iterator.ToString();
                string q = "select count(*) from event_calendar where _date='" + Convert.ToDateTime(item).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, conn);
                conn.Open();
                if ((long)(cmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0) == 0)
                {

                    strBody += i + ". " + Convert.ToDateTime(item).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(item).DayOfWeek + "  : Leave <br>";
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {

                    strBody += i + ". " + Convert.ToDateTime(item).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(item).DayOfWeek + "  : Holiday <br>";
                    i++;
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
```